# What are the precise rules for when you can omit parenthesis, dots, braces, = (functions), etc.?

Tags: syntax, scala

What are the precise rules for when you can omit (omit) parentheses, dots, braces, = (functions), etc.?

For example,

```
(service.findAllPresentations.get.first.votes.size) must be equalTo(2).
```

- `service` is my object
- `def findAllPresentations: Option[List[Presentation]]`
- `votes` returns `List[Vote]`
- *must* and *be* are both functions of specs

Why can't I go:

```
(service findAllPresentations get first votes size) must be equalTo(2)
```

?

The compiler error is:

> "RestServicesSpecTest.this.service.findAllPresentations
>   of type
>   Option[List[com.sharca.Presentation]]
>   does not take parameters"

Why does it think I'm trying to pass in a parameter? Why must I use dots for every method call?

Why must `(service.findAllPresentations get first votes size)` be equalTo(2) result in:

> "not found: value first"

Yet, the "must be equalTo 2" of
`(service.findAllPresentations.get.first.votes.size)` must be equalTo 2, that is, method chaining works fine? - object chain chain chain param.

I've looked through the Scala book and website and can't really find a comprehensive explanation.

Is it in fact, as Rob H explains in Stack Overflow question *[Which characters can I omit in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006967/scala-which-characters-can-i-omit)*, that the only valid use-case for omitting the '.' is for "operand operator operand" style operations, and not for method chaining?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### Class definitions:

`val` or `var` can be omitted from class parameters which will make the parameter private.

Adding var or val will cause it to be public (that is, method accessors and mutators are generated).

`{}` can be omitted if the class has no body, that is,

```
class EmptyClass
```

---

### Class instantiation:

Generic parameters can be omitted if they can be inferred by the compiler. However note, if your types don't match, then the type parameter is always infered so that it matches. So without specifying the type, you may not get what you expect - that is, given

```
class D[T](val x:T, val y:T);
```

This will give you a type error *(Int found, expected String)*

```
var zz = new D[String]("Hi1", 1) // type error
```

Whereas this works fine:

```
var z = new D("Hi1", 1)
== D{def x: Any; def y: Any}
```

Because the type parameter, T, is inferred as the least common supertype of the two - Any.

---

### Function definitions:

`=` can be dropped if the function returns Unit (nothing).

`{}` for the function body can be dropped if the function is a single statement, but only if the statement returns a value (you need the `=` sign), that is,

```
def returnAString = "Hi!"
```

but this doesn't work:

```
def returnAString "Hi!" // Compile error - '=' expected but string literal found."
```

The return type of the function can be omitted if it can be inferred (a recursive method must have its return type specified).

`()` can be dropped if the function doesn't take any arguments, that is,

```
def endOfString {
  return "myDog".substring(2,1)
}
```

which by convention is reserved for methods which have no side effects - more on that later.

`()` isn't actually dropped per se when defining a *[pass by name](http://hestia.typepad.com/flatlander/2009/01/scala-for-c-programmers-part-3-pass-by-name.html)* paramenter, but it is actually a quite semantically different notation, that is,

```
def myOp(passByNameString: => String)
```

Says myOp takes a pass-by-name parameter, which results in a String (that is, it can be a code block which returns a string) as opposed to function parameters,

```
def myOp(functionParam: () => String)
```

which says `myOp` takes a function which has zero parameters and returns a String.

(Mind you, pass-by-name parameters get compiled into functions; it just makes the syntax nicer.)

`()` can be dropped in the function parameter definition if the function only takes one argument, for example:

```
def myOp2(passByNameString:(Int) => String) { .. } // - You can drop the ()
def myOp2(passByNameString:Int => String) { .. }
```

But if it takes more than one argument, you must include the ():

```
def myOp2(passByNameString:(Int, String) => String) { .. }
```

---

### Statements:

`.` can be dropped to use operator notation, which can *only* be used for infix operators (operators of methods that take arguments). See [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181533/what-are-the-precise-rules-for-when-you-can-omit-parenthesis-dots-braces-f/1182099#1182099) for more information.

- `.` can also be dropped for postfix functions
  list tail
- `()` can be dropped for postfix operators
  list.tail
- `()` cannot be used with methods defined as:

  ```
  def aMethod = "hi!" // Missing () on method definition
  aMethod // Works
  aMethod() // Compile error when calling method
  ```

Because this notation is reserved by convention for methods that have no side effects, like List#tail (that is, the invocation of a function with no side effects means that the  function has no observable effect, except for its return value).

- `()` can be dropped for operator notation when passing in a single argument
- `()` may be required to use postfix operators which aren't at the end of a statement
- `()` may be required to designate nested statements, ends of anonymous functions or for operators which take more than one parameter

When calling a function which takes a function, you cannot omit the () from the inner function definition, for example:

```
def myOp3(paramFunc0:() => String) {
    println(paramFunc0)
}
myOp3(() => "myop3") // Works
myOp3(=> "myop3") // Doesn't work
```

When calling a function that takes a by-name parameter, you cannot specify the argument as a parameter-less anonymous function. For example, given:

```
def myOp2(passByNameString:Int => String) {
  println(passByNameString)
}
```

You must call it as:

```
myOp("myop3")
```

or

```
myOp({
  val source = sourceProvider.source
  val p = myObject.findNameFromSource(source)
  p
})
```

but not:

```
myOp(() => "myop3") // Doesn't work
```

IMO, overuse of dropping return types can be harmful for code to be re-used. Just look at specification for a good example of reduced readability due to lack of explicit information in the code. The number of levels of indirection to actually figure out what the type of a variable is can be nuts. Hopefully better tools can avert this problem and keep our code concise.

<sub>(OK, in the quest to compile a more complete, concise answer (if I've missed anything, or gotten something wrong/inaccurate please comment), I have added to the beginning of the answer. Please note this isn't a language specification, so I'm not trying to make it exactly academically correct - just more like a reference card.)</sub>

Comment: I’m crying. What is this.

Comment: @Profpatsch It's called overengineering

Answer (score 89):

You seem to have stumbled upon the answer. Anyway, I'll try to make it clear.

You can omit dot when using the prefix, infix and postfix notations -- the so called *operator notation*. While using the operator notation, and only then, you can omit the parenthesis if there is less than two parameters passed to the method.

Now, the operator notation is a notation for *method-call*, which means it can't be used in the absence of the object which is being called.

I'll briefly detail the notations.

**Prefix:**

Only `~`, `!`, `+` and `-` can be used in prefix notation. This is the notation you are using when you write `!flag` or `val liability = -debt`.

**Infix:**

That's the notation where the method appears between an object and it's parameters. The arithmetic operators all fit here.

**Postfix (also suffix):**

That notation is used when the method follows an object **and receives no parameters**. For example, you can write `list tail`, and that's postfix notation.

You can chain infix notation calls without problem, as long as no method is curried. For example, I like to use the following style:

```
(list
 filter (...)
 map (...)
 mkString ", "
)
```

That's the same thing as:

```
list filter (...) map (...) mkString ", "
```

Now, why am I using parenthesis here, if filter and map take a single parameter? It's because I'm passing anonymous functions to them. I can't mix anonymous functions definitions with infix style because I need a boundary for the end of my anonymous function. Also, the parameter definition of the anonymous function might be interpreted as the last parameter to the infix method.

You can use infix with multiple parameters:

```
string substring (start, end) map (_ toInt) mkString ("<", ", ", ">")
```

Curried functions are hard to use with infix notation. The folding functions are a clear example of that:

```
(0 /: list) ((cnt, string) => cnt + string.size)
(list foldLeft 0) ((cnt, string) => cnt + string.size)
```

You need to use parenthesis outside the infix call. I'm not sure the exact rules at play here.

Now, let's talk about postfix. Postfix can be hard to use, because it *can never be used anywhere except the end of an expression*. For example, you can't do the following:

```
 list tail map (...)
```

Because tail does not appear at the end of the expression. You can't do this either:

```
 list tail length
```

You could use infix notation by using parenthesis to mark end of expressions:

```
 (list tail) map (...)
 (list tail) length
```

Note that postfix notation is discouraged because [it may be unsafe](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#suffix-notation).

I hope this has cleared all the doubts. If not, just drop a comment and I'll see what I can do to improve it.

Comment: ahh, so you're saying that in my statement:  (((((realService findAllPresentations) get) first) votes) size) must be equalTo 2 - get, first, votes and size are all postfix operators, because they take no parameters? so I wonder what must, be and equalTo are...

Comment: I'm saying nothing of the sort, though I'm pretty sure that must be the case. :-) "be" is probably a helper object, to make syntax prettier. Or, more specifically, to enable use of the infix notation with "must".

Comment: Well get is Option.get, First is list.first, votes is a case class property and size is list.size. What do you think now?

Comment: Ah yes - this is all reinforced by the fact that "(realService findPresentation 1).get.id must be equalTo 1" works - as Service#findPresentations(id:Int) is an infix operator it seems. Cool - I think I get it now. :)

Answer (score 15):

A collection of quotes giving insight into the various conditions...

Personally, I thought there'd be more in the specification. I'm sure there must be, I'm just not searching for the right words...

There are a couple of sources however, and I've collected them together, but nothing really complete / comprehensive / understandable / that explains the above problems to me...:

> "If a method body has more than one
>   expression, you must surround it with
>   curly braces {…}. You can omit the
>   braces if the method body has just one
>   expression."

From [chapter 2, "Type Less, Do More", of *Programming Scala*](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch02.html):

> "The body of the upper method comes
>   after the equals sign ‘=’. Why an
>   equals sign? Why not just curly braces
>   {…}, like in Java? Because semicolons,
>   function return types, method
>   arguments lists, and even the curly
>   braces are sometimes omitted, using an
>   equals sign prevents several possible
>   parsing ambiguities. Using an equals
>   sign also reminds us that even
>   functions are values in Scala, which
>   is consistent with Scala’s support of
>   functional programming, described in
>   more detail in Chapter 8, Functional
>   Programming in Scala."

From [chapter 1, "Zero to Sixty: Introducing Scala", of *Programming Scala*](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/IntroducingScala.html):

> "A function with no parameters can be
>   declared without parentheses, in which
>   case it must be called with no
>   parentheses. This provides support for
>   the Uniform Access Principle, such
>   that the caller does not know if the
>   symbol is a variable or a function
>   with no parameters.
>
> The function body is preceded by "="
>   if it returns a value (i.e. the return
>   type is something other than Unit),
>   but the return type and the "=" can be
>   omitted when the type is Unit (i.e. it
>   looks like a procedure as opposed to a
>   function).
>
> Braces around the body are not
>   required (if the body is a single
>   expression); more precisely, the body
>   of a function is just an expression,
>   and any expression with multiple parts
>   must be enclosed in braces (an
>   expression with one part may
>   optionally be enclosed in braces)."
>
> "Functions with zero or one argument
>   can be called without the dot and
>   parentheses. But any expression can
>   have parentheses around it, so you can
>   omit the dot and still use
>   parentheses.
>
> And since you can use braces anywhere
>   you can use parentheses, you can omit
>   the dot and put in braces, which can
>   contain multiple statements.
>
> Functions with no arguments can be
>   called without the parentheses. For
>   example, the length() function on
>   String can be invoked as "abc".length
>   rather than "abc".length(). If the
>   function is a Scala function defined
>   without parentheses, then the function
>   must be called without parentheses.
>
> By convention, functions with no
>   arguments that have side effects, such
>   as println, are called with
>   parentheses; those without side
>   effects are called without
>   parentheses."

From blog post *[Scala Syntax Primer](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2008/09/scala-syntax-primer.html)*:

> "A procedure definition is a function
>   definition where the result type and
>   the equals  sign are omitted; its
>   defining expression must be a block.
>   E.g., def f (ps) {stats} is
>   equivalent to def f (ps): Unit =
>   {stats}.
>
> Example 4.6.3 Here is a declaration
>   and a de?nition of a procedure named
>   write:

```
trait Writer {
    def write(str: String)
}
object Terminal extends Writer {
    def write(str: String) { System.out.println(str) }
}
```

> The code above is implicitly completed
>   to the following code:

```
trait Writer {
    def write(str: String): Unit
}
object Terminal extends Writer {
    def write(str: String): Unit = { System.out.println(str) }
}"
```

From the language specification:

> "With methods which only take a single
>   parameter, Scala allows the developer
>   to replace the . with a space and omit
>   the parentheses, enabling the operator
>   syntax shown in our insertion operator
>   example.  This syntax is used in other
>   places in the Scala API, such as
>   constructing Range instances:

```
val firstTen:Range = 0 to 9
```

> Here again, to(Int) is a vanilla
>   method declared inside a class
>   (there’s actually some more implicit
>   type conversions here, but you get the
>   drift)."

From *[Scala for Java Refugees Part 6: Getting Over Java](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-for-java-refugees-part-6)*:

> "Now, when you try "m 0", Scala
>   discards it being a unary operator, on
>   the grounds of not being a valid one
>   (~, !, - and +). It finds that "m" is
>   a valid object -- it is a function,
>   not a method, and all functions are
>   objects.
>
> As "0" is not a valid Scala
>   identifier, it cannot be neither an
>   infix nor a postfix operator.
>   Therefore, Scala complains that it
>   expected ";" -- which would separate
>   two (almost) valid expressions: "m"
>   and "0". If you inserted it, then it
>   would complain that m requires either
>   an argument, or, failing that, a "_"
>   to turn it into a partially applied
>   function."
>
> "I believe the operator syntax style
>   works only when you've got an explicit
>   object on the left-hand side. The
>   syntax is intended to let you express
>   "operand operator operand" style
>   operations in a natural way."

[Which characters can I omit in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006967/scala-which-characters-can-i-omit)

But what also confuses me is this quote:

> "There needs to be an object to
>   receive a method call.  For instance,
>   you cannot do “println “Hello World!”"
>   as the println needs an object
>   recipient.  You can do “Console
>   println “Hello World!”" which
>   satisfies the need."

Because as far as I can see, there *is* an object to receive the call...

Comment: Ok, so tried reading the Specs source to get some clues and woah. That's a great example of the problems with magic code - too many mixins, type inference and implicit conversions and implicit parameters. It's so hard to understand from the outside in! For big libraries like that, better tooling could do some wonders... one day...

Answer (score 3):

I find it easier to follow this rule of thumb: in expressions spaces alternate between methods and parameters. In your example, `(service.findAllPresentations.get.first.votes.size) must be equalTo(2)` parses as `(service.findAllPresentations.get.first.votes.size).must(be)(equalTo(2))`. Note that the parentheses around the 2 have a higher associativity than the spaces. Dots also have higher associativity, so `(service.findAllPresentations.get.first.votes.size) must be.equalTo(2)`would parse as `(service.findAllPresentations.get.first.votes.size).must(be.equalTo(2))`.

`service findAllPresentations get first votes size must be equalTo 2` parses as `service.findAllPresentations(get).first(votes).size(must).be(equalTo).2`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, on second reading, maybe this is the key:

> With methods which only take a single
>   parameter, Scala allows the developer
>   to replace the . with a space and omit
>   the parentheses

As mentioned on the blog post: http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-for-java-refugees-part-6 .

So perhaps this is actually a very strict "syntax sugar" which *only* works where you are effectively *calling a method, on an object, which takes one parameter*. e.g.

```
1 + 2
1.+(2)
```

And nothing else.

This would explain my examples in the question.

But as I said, if someone could point out to be exactly where in the language spec this is specified, would be great appreciated.

Ok, some nice fellow (paulp_ from #scala) has pointed out where in the language spec this information is:

> 6.12.3: 
>   Precedence and associativity of
>   operators determine the grouping of
>   parts of an expression as follows.
>
> - If there are several infix operations in an expression, then
>     operators with higher precedence bind
>     more closely than operators with lower
>     precedence.
> - If there are consecutive infix operations e0 op1 e1 op2 . . .opn en
>     with operators op1, . . . , opn of the
>     same precedence, then all these
>     operators must have the same
>     associativity. If all operators are
>     left-associative, the sequence is
>     interpreted as (. . . (e0 op1 e1) op2
>     . . .) opn en. Otherwise, if all
>     operators are rightassociative, the
>     sequence is interpreted as e0 op1 (e1
>     op2 (. . .opn en) . . .).
> - Postfix operators always have lower precedence than infix operators. E.g.
>     e1 op1 e2 op2 is always equivalent to
>     (e1 op1 e2) op2.
>
> The right-hand operand of a
>   left-associative operator may consist
>   of several arguments enclosed in
>   parentheses, e.g. e op (e1, . . .
>   ,en). This expression is then
>   interpreted as e.op(e1, . . . ,en).
>
> A left-associative binary operation e1
>   op e2 is interpreted as e1.op(e2). If
>   op is rightassociative, the same
>   operation is interpreted as { val
>   x=e1; e2.op(x ) }, where x is a fresh
>   name.

Hmm - to me it doesn't mesh with what I'm seeing or I just don't understand it ;)

Comment: hmm, to further add to the confusion, this is also valid: (((((realService findAllPresentations) get) first) votes) size) must be equalTo 2, but not if i remove any of those parenthesis pairs...

Answer (score 2):

There aren't any. You will likely receive advice around whether or not the function has side-effects. This is bogus. The correction is to not use side-effects to the reasonable extent permitted by Scala. To the extent that it cannot, then all bets are off. **All** bets. Using parentheses is an element of the set "all" and is superfluous. It does not provide any value once all bets are off.

This advice is essentially an attempt at an [effect system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_system) that fails (not to be confused with: is less useful than other effect systems).

Try not to side-effect. After that, accept that all bets are off. Hiding behind a de facto syntactic notation for an effect system can and does, only cause harm.

Comment: Well, but that's the problem when you're working with a hybrid OO/ Functional language right? In any practical example you're going to want to have side effect functions... Can you point us to some information about "effect systems"? I think the more more to point quote is the "A function with no parameters can be declared without parentheses, in which case it must be called with no parentheses This provides support for the Uniform Access Principle, such that the caller does not know if the symbol is a variable or a function with no parameters.".