# Scala dotless call syntax with curried function

Tags: scala, syntax

Note: A detailed answer to the more general problem is in Stack Overflow question *[What are the precise rules for when you can omit parenthesis, dots, braces, = (functions), etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181533)*.

The following works:

```
scala> List(1,2,3) filter (_ > 1) reduceLeft(_ + _)
res65: Int = 5
```

And also the following:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).filter(_ > 1).foldLeft(0)(_ + _)
res67: Int = 5
```

But not this sytax:

```
scala> List(1,2,3) filter (_ > 1) foldLeft(0)(_ + _)
<console>:10: error: 0 of type Int(0) does not take parameters
       List(1,2,3) filter (_ > 1) foldLeft(0)(_ + _)
                                        ^
```

What is a suggested fix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This topic is well described in Stack Overflow question *[What are the precise rules for when you can omit parenthesis, dots, braces, = (functions), etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181533)*.

[Curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) functions seems to be little bit harder than methods with one parameter. To omit the dot, curried functions need to use parenthesis outside the infix call.

As [Marimuthu Madasamy mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032589/scala-dotless-call-syntax-with-curried-function/4032805#4032805), this works (the object (List), the method (foldLeft) and its first parameter (0) are in parenthesis):

```
(List(1,2,3) filter (_ > 1) foldLeft 0) (_ + _)
```

Comment: Marimuthu and you should join your answers.

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
(List(1,2,3) filter (_ > 1) foldLeft 0) (_ + _)
```