# Calling a member method without the 'this' keyword

Tags: scala

In Scala, is it possible to call a member method without having to call an instance of itself?

For instance, having this class:

```
class Model {
    def action(value : String) = {
        // Do action
    }
}
```

this object implementation works:

```
object MyModel extends Model {
    this action "doSomething"
}
```

But I would like to do something like this:

```
object MyModel extends Model {
    action "doSomething"
}
```

As one does with Java property files, since it's a neat way to define the state of an object.

I managed to define an alias for `this`:

```
def declare = this
```

but it's the same issue of having to use a word in front of the call to the member method.

Is there an option to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, but you have to use parentheses:

```
object MyModel extends Model {
    action("doSomething")
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1182099/334519) for example for more detail about when parentheses can or cannot be omitted.

As a side note, you could also alias `this` as follows:

```
object MyModel extends Model { declare =>
  declare action "doSomething"
}
```

This is often useful if you want to refer to a class's `this` from inside of a nested class—it's a bit less verbose than writing `Outer.this.x` as you would in Java.