# Option[Map[String, String]] can get a value weirdly

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I found `Option[Map[String, String]]` works weirdly like this:

```
 scala> val fileInfo: Option[Map[String, String]] = Some(Map( "type" -> "hoge" ))
 fileInfo: Option[Map[String,String]] = Some(Map(type -> hoge))

 scala> fileInfo.get("type")
 res1: String = hoge
```

I think the `Option` "get" method doesn't take any argument, so this is super weird for me. Why does it work? Is it an implicit conversion or a bug? I want to make sure how it works.

My specifications are:

- Scala version 2.9.2
- Java 1.6.0_43

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This desugars to `fileInfo.get.apply("type")`, i.e. you are not really passing a parameter to `Option#get`, but calling [`.apply("type")`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html) on the result.

Answer (score 4):

Scala allows you to [omit braces in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181533/what-are-the-precise-rules-for-when-you-can-omit-parenthesis-dots-braces-f) and you've been a victim of ambiguity that this feature created: what you've done is simply unwrapped Option (and get underlying Map) -- Option has not only widely used `.getOrElse`, but also unsafe `.get` method which fails with exception when there is None:

```
val fileInfo: Option[Map[String, String]] = Some(Map( "type" -> "hoge" ))
val map = fileInfo.get
// map: Map[String,String] = Map(type -> hoge)
// now actual map lookup
map("type")
// res0: String = hoge

// but this obviously won't work
val throwy: Option[Map[String, String]] = Option(null) // None
throwy.get("type")
// java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, that code was written by my coworker. Once I saw the code, I am like having a car accident... In this case I don't like sugar syntax, so I persuade him to change his code like your snippet.

Answer (score 2):

```
fileInfo.get("type")
```

is translated to:

```
fileInfo.get().apply("type")
```

So you unwrap the option and then get an element on the `Map`. (`apply` gets an element of the map non-optional, i.e. fails if the key doesn't exist).

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is good also, but the accepted answer is faster than yours.