# Omitting parenthesis for a method with one parameter

Tags: scala

I wonder, why doesn't this work:

```
object test {
  def method1(a: Int) = println(a)  // println a -- doesn't work either

  method1 123
}
```

`method1` takes only parameter, that is, it can be possible to omit parenthesis, can't it?

Comment: This was already answered here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181533/what-are-the-precise-rules-for-when-you-can-omit-parenthesis-dots-braces-f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a conflict with postfix operation. Let's have a look at your example:

```
 println a
```

The parser would interpret this as

```
 println.a
```

It would be very confusing if you could write

```
 println 123
```

(which is distinguishable, since `123` is not a valid method name), but now if you replace `123` by a variable holding the value, you'll get something like `member a not found on println`.

Comment: why does `startWith` work `val map2 = Map(1->"1", 2->"2") filter { kv => kv._1 startsWith "A" }`?

Comment: @MariusKavansky this is infix. the same as: `kv._1.startsWith("A")`

Comment: why is this not the same as `kv._1.startsWith."A"` ? because println a is the same as println.a