# How to use Scala subiterators "it filter p"

Tags: list, scala, iterator

In Scala doc the Operation in trait Iterator has the section of Subiterators.  How do you use them?

For example, `it filter p` describe as "An iterator returning all elements from `it` that satisfy the condition `p`.

```scala
scala> val list1 = List(1,2,3,4,5,6)
list1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

scala> list1 filter (_ > 3)
res17: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6)

scala> list1.filter(_ > 3)
res18: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6)
```

As you can see the you can use `list.filter(condition)` or `list filter (condition)`  Can someone give more examples of using these operation, and explain the difference between the two syntax format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two forms are identical.  Scala allows you to drop the dot and parentheses when the method takes exactly one argument.  So `it filter p` is the same as `it.filter(p)`.

This is how "operators" are implemented as well, since operators in Scala are just methods; so `"this" + "that"` is the same as `"this".+("that")`.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1182099/247985