# Scala REPL: error: ';' expected but string literal found

Tags: scala

What is wrong with this simple text book REPL?

```
C:\Users\abc>scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_45).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> print "Hello"
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but string literal found.
       print "Hello"
             ^

scala>
```

This is supposed to print "Hello"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the right syntax:

```
scala> print("Hello")
Hello
```

Comment: @Pangea it depends. [Sometimes, you can drop parenthesis, sometimes, you're not](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1181533/298389)

Answer (score 23):

It does work if you ask nicely:

```
scala> object please {
     |   val print = Predef.print _
     | }
defined module please

scala> please print "Hello"
Hello
```

Comment: This isnt the answer to the question. You just made it work by adding additional scaffolding code

Comment: Why not just `Predef print "hello"` directly instead of declaring `please`? Anyway, it's probably better just to use the parentheses.

Comment: @DaoWen He's definitely trolling, but I laughed anyway.