# Spark: aggregateByKey into a pair of lists

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregation

I have a keyed set of records that contain book id as well as reader id fields.

```
case class Book(book: Int, reader: Int)
```

How can I use `aggregateByKey` to combine all records with the same key into one record of the following format:

```
(key:Int, (books: List:[Int], readers: List:[Int]))
```

where books is a list of all books and readers is a list of all readers from records with the given key?

My code (below) results in compilation errors:

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

object Aggr {

  case class Book(book: Int, reader: Int)

  val bookArray = Array(
      (2,Book(book = 1, reader = 700)),
      (3,Book(book = 2, reader = 710)),
      (4,Book(book = 3, reader = 710)),
      (2,Book(book = 8, reader = 710)),
      (3,Book(book = 1, reader = 720)),
      (4,Book(book = 2, reader = 720)),
      (4,Book(book = 8, reader = 720)),
      (3,Book(book = 3, reader = 730)),
      (4,Book(book = 8, reader = 740))
  )

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    Logger.getLogger("org.apache.spark").setLevel(Level.WARN)
    Logger.getLogger("org.eclipse.jetty.server").setLevel(Level.OFF)
    // set up environment
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local[5]")
      .setAppName("Aggr")
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val books = sc.parallelize(bookArray)
    val aggr = books.aggregateByKey((List()[Int], List()[Int]))
    ({case
      ((bookList:List[Int],readerList:List[Int]), Book(book, reader)) =>
      (bookList ++ List(book), readerList ++ List(reader))
      },
    {case ((bookLst1:List[Int], readerLst1:List[Int]),
    (bookLst2:List[Int], readerLst2:List[Int])
      ) => (bookLst1 ++ bookLst2, readerLst1 ++ readerLst2) })


  }
}
```

Errors:

```
Error:(36, 44) object Nil does not take type parameters.
val aggr = books.aggregateByKey((List()[Int], List()[Int]))

Error:(37, 6) missing parameter type for expanded function The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5) Expected type was: ?
({case
 ^
                                       ^
```

**Update**

When initializing accumalator with `(List(0), List(0)` everything compiles, but inserts extra zeros into result. Very interesting:

```
val aggr :  RDD[(Int, (List[Int], List[Int]))] = books.aggregateByKey((List(0), List(0))) (
{case
  ((bookList:List[Int],readerList:List[Int]), Book(book, reader)) =>
  (bookList ++ List(book), readerList ++ List(reader))
  },
{case ((bookLst1:List[Int], readerLst1:List[Int]),
(bookLst2:List[Int], readerLst2:List[Int])
  ) => (bookLst1 ++ bookLst2, readerLst1 ++ readerLst2) }
)
```

This results in the following output:

```
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 5](2,(List(0, 1, 0, 8),List(0, 700, 0, 710)))
(3,(List(0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3),List(0, 710, 0, 720, 0, 730)))
(4,(List(0, 3, 0, 2, 8, 0, 8),List(0, 710, 0, 720, 720, 0, 740)))
```

Providing I could have empty lists as initializers instead of lists with zeros, I would not have extra zeros of course, lists would concatenate nicely.

Can somebody, please, explain me why empty list initializer `(List(), List()` results in error and `(List(0), List(0)` compiles. Is it a Scala bug or a feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your update - you misplaced the type declaration for your lists. If you declared them as `List[Int]()` instead of `List()[Int]`, everything would have worked. The compiler error message is correctly telling you the problem, but it's not quite easy to understand. By putting `[Int]` at the end, you are passing a type parameter to the **result** of the `List()` function. The result of `List()` is `Nil` - a singleton object representating an empty list - and it does not take type parameters.

As for why `List(0)` also works - scala performs *type inference*, if it can. You've declared one element of a list - which is 0, an integer, so it inferred that this is a `List[Int]`. Note however, that this does not declare an empty list, but a list with a single zero. You probably want to use `List[Int]()` instead.

Just using `List()` doesn't work because scala cannot infer the type of the empty list.

Comment: Thanks!  Scala type declarations and multi-line declarations with brackets on a wrong line, oh dear! The more I work with Scala the more I value Haskell.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you're doing everything OK, it's only that your indentation/syntax style is a bit sloppy, you just need to move one parenthesis from this:

```
val aggr = books.aggregateByKey((List()[Int], List()[Int]))
({case
```

Into this:

```
val aggr = books.aggregateByKey((List[Int](), List[Int]())) (
    {case
```

These links might shed some light why this didn't work for you:

[What are the precise rules for when you can omit parenthesis, dots, braces, = (functions), etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181533/what-are-the-precise-rules-for-when-you-can-omit-parenthesis-dots-braces-f) (first answer)

http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#suffix-notation

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately after aplying correction you have suggested I still get the same `Error:(34, 44) object Nil does not take type parameters.
    val aggr = books.aggregateByKey((List()[Int], List()[Int])) (`
                                           ^

Comment: @zork ah yes sorry I copied your code instead of what I changed in my compiler and forgot to mention it, anyway Zoltan has pointed it out already but I will change the `[Int]` declaration too