# Calling a curried method in Scala

Tags: scala, currying

When I define a curried function like:

```
def fx(x: Int) (f: Int => Int): Int = f(x)
```

I can call it using:

```
fx(2)(x => x * x)
```

But cannot call it using:

```
(fx 2) (x => x * x)
```

## However

If we take the foldLeft fun from scala std library, with signature:

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B
```

I can call it using:

```
(xs foldLeft 0 ) ( _ + _)
```

But cannot call it using:

```
xs foldLeft (0) ( _ + _)
```

## Question:

Why in case if my defined fun, I can call it using `f(x)(fx)`, but cannot call it using `(f x)(fx)`, However in case of `foldleft`, I can call it using `(obj f x)(fx)` but cannot call it using `obj f (x) (fx)` ?

Hint: I know this is because operator precedence, but need detailed answer

Comment: This has nothing to do with operator precedence

Comment: More or less duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181533/what-are-the-precise-rules-for-when-you-can-omit-parenthesis-dots-braces-f

Comment: from @Daniel C. Sobral of the question above, I could understand two things (related to my case here), 1. infix works only when on object is part of the equation (hence `(fx 2)` is not valid) 2. in case of curried functions (foldLeft), I have to surround the first infix with parenthesis before applying the send curried argument "I'm not sure the exact rules at play here". But still I need explanation.

Answer (score 2):

In your example you are not using `fx` in infix position. A function or operator in *infix* requires an instance where this function is called on left of the function or operator and an argument to the right.

Example:

```
(xs foldLeft 0 ) ( _ + _)
```

`foldLeft`(infix) is called on `xs` (left) - which is some *Collection* - passing `0`(right) as argument.

In your example:

```
(fx 2) (x => x * x)
```

The object `fx` is called on is missing. If you change your example a bit, it works:

```
object someInstance {
  def fx(x: Int)(f: Int => Int): Int = f(x)

  val test = (this fx 2) (x => x * x)
}

// OR
val test2 = (someInstance fx 2) (x => x * x)
```

It would work.

Comment: Okay, this is part is clear (see my comments on the question) - thanks to @sschaef, what about the other part?