# Scalatest call be without parenthesis

Tags: scala, scalatest, infix-notation

Why does the following code fails:

```
session.getGameId should be 10
```

with this error

```
';' expected but integer literal found.
```

However this one doesn't fail

```
session.getGameId should be(10)
```

Does it have to do with the way that the `apply` method is called

Comment: Note that more recent versions of Scalatest offer alternative forms to write `result shouldBe 10` or `result shouldEqual 10` without parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
session.getGameId should be 10
```

means

```
(session.getGameId).should(be).(10)
```

whereas

```
session.getGameId should be(10)
```

means

```
(session.getGameId).should(be(10))
```

Obviously, the first one can't compile since it is not valid to call an integer literal in this position. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181533/what-are-the-precise-rules-for-when-you-can-omit-parenthesis-dots-braces-f) for further explanation when you can leave out parentheses and dots in Scala.