# Is `dataframe.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)text(output)` valid Scala/Spark SQL syntax?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

So I had a typo of `dataframe.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)text(output)` missing a period between `mode` and `text`, but eclipse doesn't seem to complain, and when I run it through Junit and production, everything seems to run fine without exception, even producing correct output. I am confused that there wasn't any bug, and my Spark DAG does show that my code has changed, so I am more confused. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the precise rules for when you can omit parenthesis, dots, braces, = (functions), etc.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181533/what-are-the-precise-rules-for-when-you-can-omit-parenthesis-dots-braces-f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just the way scala works. It's the [Infix notation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html)

A white space is not required because of the parentheses.
Here is a demonstration :

```
scala> val l = List(1,2,3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> l.take(1)
res4: List[Int] = List(1)

scala> l take 1
res5: List[Int] = List(1)

scala> (l)take 1
res6: List[Int] = List(1)

scala> l.take(2)take(1)
res7: List[Int] = List(1)
```

Comment: So you don't even need to have a space between two methods? I suppose it should have been at least something like write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite) text(output) or something

Comment: I've added a demo to illustrate this

Comment: Still confused because it seems like most of the use cases seem to have at least space between method names, but mine doesn't have any space between two methods.

Comment: I've added a last example, but did you read the documentation I've linked to my answer ? everything is explained there