# removing parenthesis if method has no argument/no side effects

Tags: scala

I read that if a  method takes no argument and has no side-effects, parenthesis can be removed to improve readability (spartan implementation). So I can call following code

```
def withoutP = {
        println(s"without p")
    }
withoutP
```

Then I found this code which takes arguments but I can still call it without parenthesis. How?

```
def isEven(n: Int) = (n % 2) == 0
List(1, 2, 3, 4) filter isEven foreach println
```

I tried running this code but it didn't work. Why?

```
def withP(i:Int) = {

    println("with p")
}
withP 1

';' expected but integer literal found.
[error]                 withP 1
[error]                       ^
[error] one error found
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the precise rules for when you can omit parenthesis, dots, braces, = (functions), etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181533/what-are-the-precise-rules-for-when-you-can-omit-parenthesis-dots-braces-f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example

```
def isEven(n: Int) = (n % 2) == 0
List(1, 2, 3, 4) filter isEven foreach println
```

you don't actually call `isEven`. You call `filter`, which is a method on `List`, and `isEven` is the parameter for `filter`. `filter` calls `isEven` for every value in the list, using the value as the argument.

`filter` is written in the [infix notation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#infix-notation), which is legal for methods that accept only one argument. The alternative is

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4).filter(isEven)
```

The `.` is also required in this case, because `filter` is a method in the `List` class.

Comment: That is my doubt. If `filter` takes an argument (`isEven`), how come I can write `filter isEven` without parenthesis i.e. `filter(isEven)`

Answer (score 1):

1.For first example, invoke `withoutP` without parameter, this compiles is by Scala allows the omission of parentheses on methods of [arity-0 (no arguments)](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html)

2.For second example, invoke `withoutP 1` with a parameter, this not compile is caused by [Infix notation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html) need to **start with a object**. so you can achieve parentheses by:

```
this withP 1 //infix notation with this (current object)
```

so for the `1` and `2` are not the same omission parentheses rules. First is the `arity-0` rule, and Second should use `Infix notation` to omit parentheses.