# Scala dot syntax (or lack thereof)

Tags: java, syntax, scala

I was going through the wonderful book *[Programming in Scala](http://booksites.artima.com/programming_in_scala)* when I came across a piece of code that just doesn't make sense to me:

```
def above(that: Element): Element = {
    val this1 = this widen that.width
    val that1 = that widen this.width
    elem(this1.contents ++ that1.contents)
}
```

Note line 2 and 3:

```
val this1 = this widen that.width
```

It seems like I should be able to replace this with:

```
val this1 = this.widen that.width
```

However, when I try to compile this change, it gives the following error:

> error: ';' expected but '.' found.        
>      val this1 = this.widen that.width
>                                  ^

Why is this syntax unacceptable?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181533/what-are-the-precise-rules-for-when-you-can-omit-parenthesis-dots-braces-fu and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006967/scala-which-characters-can-i-omit

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Line 2 uses the method `widen` as an operator, instead of using it as a method in the Java way:

```
val this1 = this.widen(that.width)
```

The error occurs because you've left out the parentheses, which you can only do when you use a method in operator notation. You **can't** do this for example:

```
"a".+ "b" // error: ';' expected but string literal found.
```

Instead you should write

```
"a".+ ("b")
```

Actually you can do this with integers, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Read more:

- Chapter 5 section 3 of your book is about the operator notation, at least in the first edition, version 5
- [A Tour of Scala: Operators](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/118)

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it but maybe this works: `val this1 = this.widen(that.width)`

`widen` is probably a method taking one parameter (plus the `this` reference), such methods can be used like operators as in your first sample code.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a dot you are using dot-style for method invocation. When you don't, you are using operator-style. You can't mix both syntaxes for the very same method invocation, though you can mix the two for different invocations -- such as that.width used as a parameter in the operator style invocation of widen.

Please refer to [Which characters can I omit in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006967/scala-which-characters-can-i-omit) or [What are the precise rules for when you can omit parenthesis, dots, braces, = (functions), etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181533/what-are-the-precise-rules-for-when-you-can-omit-parenthesis-dots-braces-fu).