# Scala DSL, Object and infix notation

Tags: scala, dsl, scala-2.8, infix-notation

in Scala, if I want to implement a DSL, is there a way to do the following:

I have an Object called "Draw" which contains the function `def draw(d:Drawable)`

how can I make it so that I can import the Object and call it outside the object like:

```
draw ball
```

if ball extends the Drawable trait? The problem is that I want to use draw in a kind of infix notation, but I dont want to qualify the function draw by denoting it's implementing class/object.

Comment: The following thread may shed some light on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006967/scala-which-characters-can-i-omit

To summarize: only `~`, `!`, `-` and `+` can be used for infix or unary operators, but not `draw`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quickly tried it out, but could quite make it work using an object. There I had to use draw(ball) instead of draw ball, as you wanted:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.0.RC2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_20).
```

scala> trait Drawable{def doSomething}
defined trait Drawable

scala> object Draw {
        def draw(d:Drawable) = d.doSomething
     }
defined module Draw

scala> val ball = new Drawable{def doSomething = println("doing ball")}
ball: java.lang.Object with Drawable = $anon$1@3a4ba4d6

scala> import Draw._
import Draw._

scala> draw ball
:11: error: missing arguments for method draw in object Draw;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
       draw ball
       ^

scala> draw(ball)
doing ball

However by defining Draw as a class, it did work:

```
scala> trait Drawable{def doSomething: Unit}
defined trait Drawable
```

scala> class Draw {
        def draw(d:Drawable) = d.doSomething
     }
defined class Draw

scala>

scala> val ball = new Drawable{def doSomething = println("doing ball")}
ball: java.lang.Object with Drawable = $anon$1@36a06816

scala> val d = new Draw
d: Draw = Draw@7194f467

scala> d draw ball
doing ball

I'm not completely sure why this doesn't work the same way with an object, might be a bug or perhaps that's specified behaviour. However I didn't have the time to look it up at the moment.

Comment: The problem with your first version is that Scala's "operator notation" needs an explicit receiver, that's why the class example works.

Comment: I think draw(ball) could be acceptable syntax. I would have something like draw(ball) at (x,y,z) on someOpenGlPanel. It is just a test of doing a small DSL anyway :) Thanks for your answer.

Btw: maybe one could accept some filler symbol like Draw -> ball or whatever...back to thinking :)

Comment: Another option would be to rename the draw method to "the". In this way your example would become: "Draw the ball"

Answer (score 6):

You can't do it. Aside from four prefix operators, in any operator notation the first token represents the object.

Comment: Actually, Felix _could_ do it by making `draw` an object and `ball` a method of an anonymous class of an implicit conversion that referenced the real object.  I doubt he, or anyone else, would prefer that, so +1 for this answer.