# Scala - Prefix Unary Operators

Tags: scala, logic, notation, unary-operator

I've recently given Scala a second chance, and started with the project I always implement (in functional or pseudo-functional languages): an automated reasoner for propositional logic (and later predicate logic).

Now, I've tried to get the notation of propositional logic in the language itself as pretty as possible, and I've gotten this far - with an implicit conversion (String -> Atom):

```
("A" and "B") implies "C"
```

The functions "and" and "implies" (and "or" and "equivalent") are simple methods that call the relevant case class constructor. However, when implementing "not", I get stuck with either of the two following notations:

```
("A" and "B").not
Not("A" and "B")
```

Is there a way to trick Scala into accepting the desired:

```
not("A" and "B")
```

Preferrably without renaming the class "Not" to "not", because I might like to call it "¬" or something else, in th future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Feb 2014, I think the cleanest way to define a prefix'ish `not` operation on expressions, while avoiding all sorts of extra cruft/wrapping, would be to declare the function directly in the package scope, together with all your other functions, classes, types etc: This is done by defining a package object (Scala doesn't allow you to just put functions at the root level of the `.scala` file (I'd love to learn why—is it just to follow Java's footsteps?)).

```scala
package org.my.logiclib

implicit class Atom(s: String) { ... }
class MyType1
class MyType2

object `package` {
  def not(expr: Expr) = ...
}
```

this way, doing `import org.my.logiclib._` will import everything, including `not()`.

The above is the same as

```
package org.my

package logiclib {
  implicit class Atom ...
  ...

  def not(expr: Expr) = ...
}
```

Answer (score 23):

I noticed on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006967/scala-which-characters-can-i-omit/1014972#1014972) to another question that it appears that one can prefix the operator name with `unary_` to achive what you are trying to do. (See `unary_!`.)

Edit: [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-scala02198.html) confirms the syntax.

Comment: That doesn't work with custom operator names though. I.e. you can't define `unary_not` to get a prefix "not"-operator.

Comment: Specifically `prefix_` only works with `!`, `~`, `+` and `-`.

Comment: @sepp2k: Thanks, did not realise this subtlty.  This restriction seems like a bit of a shame (and completely arbitrary).

Comment: @Paul: I don't think it's that arbitrary. I would imagine that not having that restriction would make parsing quite a pain. You wouldn't know whether `foo bar` should parse as `foo.bar()` or `bar.unary_foo()` until after typechecking (and you'd still need rules to decide which one should be chosen if both are possible).

Comment: Still, this means I could implement it as the "!" or "~" operator, which is what I'm after.

Comment: @Dennetik: If you go with `!` instead of `not`, remember that scala also allows you to define `&&`, `||` and `->`, so you don't have to mix operators and words.

Answer (score 14):

You can define `not` as a method on a singleton object, like this:

```
object Logic {
  def not(x:Expr) = Not(x)
}
import Logic._
not("A" and "B")
```

(Where `Expr` is supposed to be the common superclass of `And`, `Or`, `Not` and `Atom`)

Edit: Here's an example of how this could be used with only a single import:

```
object Logic {
  abstract class Expr {
    def and(e: Expr) = Conjunction(this, e)
    def or(e: Expr) = Disjunction(this, e)
    def implies(e: Expr) = Implication(this, e)
  }
  case class Conjunction(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
  case class Disjunction(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
  case class Implication(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
  case class Negation(e: Expr) extends Expr
  case class Atom(name: String) extends Expr

  def not(e: Expr) = Negation(e)
  implicit def string2atom(str: String) = Atom(str)
}

// use site
import Logic._
not("A" and "B") implies (not("A") or not("B"))
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I could use "static imports" in Scala - this would leave me with a mandatory import on each page, though, which - together with the implicit conversion would be a a lot of extra code for each use.

Comment: @Dennetik: If you simply put everything into the Logic object, `import Logic._` is all you need to use your classes.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that, I still have to get used to Scala's freedom, compared to Java...

Comment: You can also put functions directly into packages, side by side with classes, so you don't need to define a `Logic` wrapper object; see [package objects](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html)

Answer (score 8):

Why `Not` instead of `not`? There's nothing to stop you from doing this:

```
object not {
  def apply(expr: T) = ...
}
```

And then use `not("A" and "B")`.

Comment: why is everybody always finding ways around putting functions directly into packages using package objects...

Comment: @ErikAllik Because in 2010 there were no package objects.

Comment: Good point! Didn't realise that—Thanks :) P.S. however, would you use one today for defining `not(expr: T)`?