# Is there a way to create dot-free dsl in scala with two identifiers between variables?

Tags: scala

Is there a way to define a dsl, that would allow the following form?

```
variable identifier identifier variable
```

For example:

```
1 equals to 2
```

I know how to create a simpler form: `1 equals to (2)`, but I want to avoid parentheses. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can ask the parser:

```
$ scala -Xprint:parser
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 ... blah

scala> variable1 identifier1 identifier2 variable2
// lots of stuff and inside:
val res0 = variable1.identifier1(identifier2).variable2
// this is how the parser sees it.
// if you can make that work (dynamic classes…?), you’re good to go.
```

However, there is a problem: This only works as long as `variable2` is an identifier (so that it can be used as a method name). With

```
scala> 1 equals to 2
```

already the parser fails:

```
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but integer literal found.
       1 equals to 2
                   ^
```

Parentheses are really your only way around(*):

```
scala> 1 equals to (2)
// ...
val res1 = 1.equals(to(2))
```

---

(*) unless you make `2` an identifier by using it with backticks

```
scala> 1 equals to `2`
// ...
val res2 = 1.equals(to).2
```

… nah, maybe not.

Comment: Ah, nice trick with the parser output. I'm sure that will prove to be handy once again.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know it's impossible at the moment to implement it as you want (I would be happy to be proven wrong). I also faced this issue, when I was creating my small DSL for injection. But I have realized, that even if you can't have 2 variables between 2 identifiers, you still can have three identifiers between them. It looks like this:

```
variable1 method constant method variable2
```

which is the same as:

```
variable1.method(constant).method(variable2)
```

With this I was able to come up with very nice DSL that looks like this:

```
by default defaultDb and identified by 'remote
'remote is by default defaultDb
```

You can find more examples of it's usage in this spec:

https://github.com/OlegIlyenko/scaldi/blob/48f7e4186cf7eb441116087003d7f45f16e0ac6c/src/test/scala/scaldi/InjectableSpec.scala#L47

It's implementation can be found here:

https://github.com/OlegIlyenko/scaldi/blob/master/src/main/scala/scaldi/Injectable.scala

I used `ByWord` and `IdentifiedWord` class types as method arguments. For example:

```
def is(by: ByWord) = and(by)
```

Which leaves possibility, that users of the library will extend `ByWorld` class and generally can provide their own `ByWorld` implementations. Now when I think about this, I find it not very nice. Better solution would be to create singelton objects for the constant words and then use their type like this:

```
object by
def is(byWord: by.type) = and(by)
```

This generally restricts argument to only one possible `by` word instance.

Comment: Yeah, I know about three-identifier solution :)

Answer (score 1):

#### [Unary Operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014972/1287856)

Well, you can have two successive identifiers if the final one is a unary operator:

```
a identifier1 - d
```

is parsed as

```
a.identifier1(d.unary_-)
```

Note that unary functions can be only ! ~ and -

#### [Dynamic methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799811/how-does-type-dynamic-work-and-how-to-use-it)

If you don't mind to have your last variable name treated as a string (e.g. you have a way to later retrieve its value from a map or the [interpreter itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14223796/1287856)), you can have the following using dynamics:

```
import scala.Dynamic
import scala.language.dynamics

class I2
class Res(i: I2) extends Dynamic {
  def selectDynamic(obj: String): Unit = {
      println(obj)
    }
}
class V1 { def i1(i2: I2): Res= new Res(i2) }
val v1 = new V1
val i2 = new I2

v1 i1 i2 v2
```

results in the string "v2".