# Scala syntax bug?

Tags: scala, syntax

I have encountered with something I think is a bug/no-syntax-sense in scala syntax but I prefer to post it here after reporting it as I might be wrong.

The controller class:

```
package some

import java.awt.event.ActionListener
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent

class ItemController extends ActionListener {

  val NEW_ITEM = "new item"
  val UPDATE_ITEM = "update item"

  private val newItem = new ItemNew

  override def actionPerformed(e: ActionEvent) = {

  }

  def create(view: String) = {

    view match {
      case NEW_ITEM => {
        newItem eraseForm //Here eclipse says "Unit does not take parameters".
        newItem setVisible true
      }

      case UPDATE_ITEM =>
    }

  }

}
```

The view class

```
  package some

  import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
  import javax.swing.JPanel
  import java.awt.GridLayout
  import javax.swing.JFrame
  import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap
  import javax.swing.JTextField
  import java.awt.BorderLayout
  import java.awt.FlowLayout
  import javax.swing.JLabel

  class ItemNew extends JFrame {

    private val formFields = LinkedHashMap[String, JTextField]()

    init

    private def init(): Unit = {
      // defining form fields
      formFields += ("name" -> new JTextField(20),
        "surname" -> new JTextField(20),
        "age" -> new JTextField(3))

      setLayout(new BorderLayout)

      val formPanel = new JPanel
      formPanel setLayout (new GridLayout(formFields.size, 1))

      generateForm(formPanel)
      getContentPane add formPanel

      pack
      setVisible(true)

      def generateForm(formPanel: JPanel) = {

        var leftPanel: JPanel = null
        var rightPanel: JPanel = null
        var gridPanel: JPanel = null

        formFields foreach (entry => {

          leftPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout)
          leftPanel.getLayout().asInstanceOf[FlowLayout] setAlignment FlowLayout.LEFT

          rightPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout)
          rightPanel.getLayout.asInstanceOf[FlowLayout] setAlignment FlowLayout.LEFT

          gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2))

          leftPanel add new JLabel(entry._1 + ':')
          rightPanel add entry._2

          gridPanel add leftPanel
          gridPanel add rightPanel

          formPanel add gridPanel

        })
      }
    }

    def getFormContent: HashMap[String, String] = {

      val formData = HashMap[String, String]()

      formFields foreach (entry => {
        formData += (entry._1 -> entry._2.getText)
      })

      return formData
    }

    def eraseForm : Unit = {
      formFields foreach (entry => {
        entry._2 setText ""
      })
    }

    private def addListeners = {

    }

  }
```

See the comment in the ItemController class. If I leave a blank line between the statement where the comment is and the `newItem setVisible true` then the code gives no error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
newItem eraseForm
newItem setVisible true
```

is parsed as

```
newItem.eraseForm(
newItem).setVisible(true);
```

but what you want to have is:

```
newItem.eraseForm;
newItem.setVisible(true);
```

Leaving out dots and parentheses means that the Scala compiler applies "operator notation". This means that your expression always needs to be of the form `obj meth param`. It is possible to have `obj meth;` but as you can see this form needs to be stopped by a semicolon. You can either insert it by yourself or let the compiler infer it by adding an empty line, an expression that starts with a keyword in the following line or with closing braces and parentheses.

Since 2.10 you will also get a warning if you write `obj meth` because such postfix operators can be harmful as you can see with your question.

See these two question and their answers for more information on the "operator notation" rule:

- [Which characters can I omit in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006967/which-characters-can-i-omit-in-scala)
- [What are the precise rules for when you can omit parenthesis, dots, braces, = (functions), etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181533/what-are-the-precise-rules-for-when-you-can-omit-parenthesis-dots-braces-f)